# Почему неправильно считает глубину массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Глубина массива в примере равна 2, а код выводит 3? Проблема в замыкании, поясните пожалуйста как это работает?

```
    let res = 1
function f(arr) {
    console.log(`arr - ${arr}`)
    arr.forEach(item => {
        if(Array.isArray(item)){
            ++res
            f(item,res)
        }
    })
}

f([1, 2, 3, [1], 4, 5, [1]])
```

Comment: Вы перебираете элементы массива `arr`, и если элемент является массивом, наращиваете счётчик. Наткнулись на элемент `[1]` по индексу `3` — нарастили счётчик. Наткнулись на элемент `[1]` по индексу `6` —нарастили счётчик.

Comment: Тут определённо уже был вопрос про глубину вложенности массивов, но что-то не могу его найти....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если несколько элементов *текущего* массива сами являются массивами, то не нужно наращивать счётчик глубины на *каждом* элементе-массиве. Нужно посчитать глубину для каждого элемента-массива и выбрать из них максимальную. Итоговая глубина для текущего массива — это максимальная среди глубин элементов-массивов + 1.

Как-то так:

```
function searchArrDepth(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr))
        return 0;

    let depth = 0;
    for (let item of arr)
        depth = Math.max(depth, searchArrDepth(item));
    return 1 + depth;
}
```

Или более компактно:

```js
function searchArrDepth(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr))
        return 0;
    return 1 + arr.reduce((depth, item) => Math.max(depth, searchArrDepth(item)), 0);
}
    
console.log(searchArrDepth( [1, 2, 3, [1], 4, 5, [1]] ));
console.log(searchArrDepth( [] ));
console.log(searchArrDepth( [1, 2, 3] ));
console.log(searchArrDepth( [[1], [2], [3]] ));
console.log(searchArrDepth( [1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6]]]]]] ));
console.log(searchArrDepth( {} ));
console.log(searchArrDepth( [[[[[]]]]] ));
```

---

Например, пусть есть массив вида (здесь `[...]` обозначает некоторый массив)

```
arr = [1, [...], 3, [...], 5];
```

У данного массива `5` элементов. Причём два из них — это элементы-массивы. Подсчитаем сколь глубоко здесь вложены массивы.

Во-первых, учитываем сам массив `arr` и полагаем, что глубина равна `1`.

Теперь переберём элементы массива `arr` и для каждого элемента найдём его глубину. Если элемент не является массивом (`!Array.isArray(arr[i]) === true`), то считаем, что его глубина равна нулю. Получившийся массив глубин может быть, например, таким:

```
[0, 1, 0, 5, 0]
```

Среди всех найденных глубин выберем максимальную — `5`.

Итоговая глубина есть максимальная среди всех глубин элементов массива `arr` (т.е. `5`) + `1` (учли сам массив `arr`).

Заметим, что массив глубин `[0, 1, 0, 5, 0]` не обязательно формировать явно. Мы можем последовательно перебирать элементы массива `arr`, сравнивая их глубину с текущей максимальной глубиной, и при необходимости обновлять текущую максимальную глубину. Т.е. как-то так:

```
depth = 0;

depth = max(depth, searchArrDepth(arr[0])) = max(0, 0) = 0
depth = max(depth, searchArrDepth(arr[1])) = max(0, 1) = 1
depth = max(depth, searchArrDepth(arr[2])) = max(1, 0) = 1
depth = max(depth, searchArrDepth(arr[3])) = max(1, 5) = 5
depth = max(depth, searchArrDepth(arr[4])) = max(5, 0) = 5
```

Именно это и делает код

```
for (let item of arr)
    depth = Math.max(depth, searchArrDepth(item));
```

Здесь `item` последовательно принимает значения `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, и т.д.
Для каждого элемента массива мы находим его глубину `searchArrDepth(item)`, и обновляем максимум `depth = Math.max(depth, searchArrDepth(item))`.

Наконец, возвращаем из функции максимум среди глубин  элементов + `1` (сам массив `arr`): `return 1 + depth;`.

И самое главное, наш массив `arr` ничем принципиально не отличается от своих элементов-массивов. Также как для каждого элемента массива `arr` мы вызываем функцию `searchArrDepth`, так и для самого массива `arr` мы можем вызвать функцию `searchArrDepth`.

Comment: не понимаю, как работает Math.max() и рекурсия. Можете подробнее объяснить если не составит труда

Comment: @vlad, расписал алгоритм подробнее.

Comment: спасибо огромное